# Programmatically deploy to Heroku

Tags: git, go, heroku

I'm looking some help for programmatically deploying app to Heroku. Heroku have a cli application for manage your apps. On command `heroku login` write to `~/.netrc` API key:

```
machine api.heroku.com
  login email@gmail.com
  password 6450sdf8-bd51-40da-9706-e39s85mc251f
```

In docs I can find this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#http-git-authentication where writen

> The Heroku HTTP Git endpoint only accepts API-key based HTTP Basic authentication. A username is not required and any value passed for username is ignored.

My code using https://github.com/src-d/go-git:

```golang
    r, err := git.PlainOpen("go-getting-started")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    r.CreateRemote(&config.RemoteConfig{
        Name: "heroku",
        URLs: []string{"https://git.heroku.com/afternoon-ocean-91922.git"},
    })

    err = r.Push(&git.PushOptions{
        Auth: &http.BasicAuth{
            Username: "email@gmail.com",
            Password: "6450sdf8-bd51-40da-9706-e39s85mc251f",
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

And have error

> 2020/01/30 17:38:23 authentication required
>
> exit status 1

Ok, then I `set -i; GIT_TRACE=2 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=2 GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=2 GIT_TRACE_PACK_ACCESS=2 GIT_TRACE_PACKET=2 GIT_TRACE_PACKFILE=2 GIT_TRACE_SETUP=2 GIT_TRACE_SHALLOW=2 git push heroku master -v -v; set +i` and see in log this lines

```
Host: git.heroku.com
User-Agent: git/2.25.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Accept-Language: ru-RU, *;q=0.9
Pragma: no-cache

* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Date: Thu, 30 Jan 2020 15:00:44 GMT
< Request-Id: c0786480-055d-40bc-90b3-d795304c2777
< Server: endosome/development (instance=6283027; pid=4272)
< Www-Authenticate: Basic realm="Heroku"
< Content-Length: 249
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host git.heroku.com left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://git.heroku.com/infinite-garden-93715.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack'
* Found bundle for host git.heroku.com: 0x5616ad25b0a0 [serially]
* Can not multiplex, even if we wanted to!
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host git.heroku.com
* Connected to git.heroku.com (54.225.111.180) port 443 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'email@gmail.com'
> GET /infinite-garden-93715.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1
Host: git.heroku.com
Authorization: Basic aHJkY29ka...Mzk2MmJkZTI1MWY=
User-Agent: git/2.25.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Accept-Language: ru-RU, *;q=0.9
Pragma: no-cache
```

The line `aHJkY29ka...Mzk2MmJkZTI1MWY=` in

> Authorization: Basic aHJkY29ka...Mzk2MmJkZTI1MWY=

is `email:token` in base64.
Why I can't success auth with key from `~/.netrc`? How I can push to remote repository programmatycally? Thanks!

Comment: "If you’re using other Git clients, such as EGit or Tower, configure them to use an empty string for username (or any string you like – it’s ignored) and your account API key for password. The API key is available in the CLI and in Dashboard." - have you tried that?

Comment: @Laney If the username string is ignored, then my mail in this case should also be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

For deploying git to Heroku, your .netrc file should also contain git.heroku.com login credentials in addition to api.heroku.com credentials

```
machine api.heroku.com
  login email@gmail.com
  password 6450sdf8-bd51-40da-9706-e39s85mc251f
machine git.heroku.com
  login email@gmail.com
  password 6450sdf8-bd51-40da-9706-e39s85mc251f
```